# Sorting according to duplication with multiple subset of duplication within a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to python, and I wanted to sort some duplication data according to some column of data within a data frame set, for example

```
Import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('Data.xlsx', index = ['ID']
df2 = df[df.duplicated(subset = ['A','B'], keep = False)]
print (df2)
```

Let's say the output will be like this

```
'ID'|'Name' |'A'|'B'|
1   | Ash   | 1 | 1 |
2   | James | 1 | 1 |
3   | Ash   | 1 | 1 |
4   | James | 1 | 1 |
5   | Ash   | 2 | 1 |
6   | James | 1 | 1 |
7   | Ash   | 2 | 1 |
```

I would like to have the output of data as below:

```
'Name' |'A'|'B'|'Pattern'|'Frequency of Pattern'|
Ash    | 1 | 1 |    1    |           2          |
Ash    | 2 | 1 |    2    |           2          |
James  | 1 | 1 |    3    |           3          |
```

So far I haven't found any similar post yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for count duplicates and then add new column to specific position by [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df4 = df3.groupby(['Name','A','B']).size().reset_index(name='Frequency of Pattern')
df4.insert(3, 'Pattern', df4.index + 1)
print (df4)
    Name  A  B  Pattern  Frequency of Pattern
0    Ash  1  1        1                     2
1    Ash  2  1        2                     2
2  James  1  1        3                     3
```